# Window dialogs fire twice inside event handler

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to show a dialog when an input changes, but the dialog is shown *twice* when `onChange` is called. Here is the problem reproduced from a fresh `create-react-app`:

```
function App() {
    let handleChange = (e) => {
        // this fires twice every time you change the input using the little arrows, but NOT when changed manually
        alert("changed!");
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="number" defaultValue={0} onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is this a bug? What do I have to do differently? I'm testing this using Chrome on Windows.

Comment: It looks like it actually increments the number twice! Check this out https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/17098

Comment: @MosheSommers Though... that link is pretty old and I'm on windows

Comment: Yup! That doesn't seem very relevant anymore. My bad.

Comment: It only fires twice when you have an alert dialog. If you instead log it will behave correctly

Comment: @MosheSommers It fires twice with any window dialog (I'm actually using `confirm` in my project). It's just easier to exemplify `alert`. In any case, do you see anything obvious that needs to change to avoid this behavior? Other than reworking/reinventing my own dialog?